# Can't bootstrap an angular app

Tags: angularjs

I was following the angular docs and other links in order to create a "component" with angular inside a rails-based project.

The problem is that I can't correctly initialize the app, and instead I got two identical errors

```
Uncaught Error: No module: testApp0
Uncaught Error: No module: testApp0
```

In the following jsfiddle I try to show you my point http://jsfiddle.net/d8Lyu/

I'm pretty new in angular and the official documentation isn't very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost here! Just remember angular is modular and every module need to be declared with an `angular.module('my_module_name', ['my_modules_dependency'])`.

Just refactor your code like that :

```
angular.module( //this is your app module
    'testApp0',
    ['testApp0.controllers'] //your app need your controller as a dependency to works
  );

  angular.module( //this is your controller module
    'testApp0.controllers',
    []
  ).controller('sliderCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.greeting = "hellow" //you pass a gretting variable to your template
        }
    ])
```

An other thing : you declare a `gretting` variable in your controller but acces it with `user.hellow` in your template. Just put `{{ gretting }}`.

One last thing, in the

> frameworks and extensions

of fiddle change 'onLoad' to 'in body', you don't want your angular app to be ready before the DOM.

If you plan to use angular, look at : [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app). The tutorial app can't be trusted for serious angular developement.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jsfiddle as a reference: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/

You need to add an external resource, change settings in the 'fiddle options' section and the 'frameworks and extensions' section.

Once everything is setup you can create your angular in the javascript pane likeso:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, htanks for the fiddle advice, but in fact that was the way I intent to change. I have another thing in the rails project, but I tried to simplify the issue that I was having

Comment: Also, thank you for your jsfiddle, helps a lot to understand other things